# delete mysql using button and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to delete files in my database instantly when I press a button. Files were deleted but I am obliged to refresh my navigator. Ajax doesn't operate.

**HTML/PHP**

```
  echo '<button class="delete_video" id="'.$videoId.'" type="button">Delete</button>';
```

**javaScript**

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".delete_video").click(function()
        {
            var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:'delete_id='+del_id,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //confirmation of deletion
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
include('functions.php');
$DB = connexion();
$DB->query('DELETE FROM videos WHERE id = "'.$id.'"');
```

Comment: You said the files were deleted, so what is the problem? Refreshing the page after deleting? If so then just add location.reload() to the success function.

Comment: Yes, the refreshing is the problem.  Thank's you solded the problem.

Comment: Nadir; I noticed you accepted an answer below and there is no explanation given for it, it's just "drop-in" code and probably based on the comment given up here. You should have told/asked @jussius to submit an answer for it, since that person was the first one to give you the solution; I feel it's only fair.

Comment: You're also open to a serious SQL injection @Nadir

Comment: @jussius I suggest you post an answer for this and not just "drop-in" code like the answer given originally. I'm sure Nadir will accept it. ;-)

Comment: An injection ? Wow, I don't know the issue of this problem but thank you for having informed me.

Comment: @Nadir Yes. Read the following http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php they will help you. Using a prepared statement is important. and you're welcome.

Comment: You're welcome Nadir, *cheers*

Comment: @Nadir further to my comment; you can also just do `$id = (int)$_POST['delete_id'];` if the id is an integer/number. However, using a prepared statement in conjunction with this, will be even better.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Also, what Fred said about injections is true, you should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `location.reload()` to the success function.

That is the syntax to use.

Plus, you're also open to a serious SQL injection.

Consult the following:

- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".delete_video").click(function()
        {
            var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:'delete_id='+del_id,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //reload page
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping there are rows you are deleting so make sure that you pass an id element to each row as

---

here goes your video

---

and when your AJAX return success just make the element disappear

```
 <div id="del_id">
      here goes your video to delete
 </div>


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".delete_video").click(function()
    {
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            data:'delete_id='+del_id,
            success: function(data)
            {
                jQuery('#del_id').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```